# Need a micro chip

Tags: microcontroller

I'm from the software industry and looking for an electronic device. Maybe it is already commercially available and has a famous name, but I don't know that, so I'll describe its properties and maybe someone could guide me to what it is called, so here we go:

1. I need a chip/circuit/micro-controller (whatever it is called) of size less than 1x1 inch (smaller the better) that could communicate with other chips of its own type. It should send out a signal and get reply back from the target and compute the total time it took for the message to travel. I'll then be using triangulation to compute the position of these chips.
2. The operation field is roughly 100 meters wide and I may need about 15 to 20 chips in the entire field.
3. Devices may not be place in line of sight, so please suggest the type of signal (radio, infra-red, ultrasound) as well.
4. If we use radio, the response will come back really quickly in a range of 100 meters, so we'll probably need a very fast timer in the chips because I need millimeter-level accuracy.
5. Last but not the least the chip should be able to communicate with a PC too. An application on the PC will be doing the triangulation work.

This is the basic of what I need. If there is a commercial product that already does this, please let me know what it is called.

## EDIT

As some of the readers were curious to know, here's our idea:

We're basically planning a cricket trainer (or any bat/ball game for that matter). These small chips would be installed on the surface of the ball and the bat, and will communicate their distance from a central device to the PC. The PC will then use triangulation and other algorithms to compute the position, speed, rotation speed and other factors for both the ball and the bat, and thus be able to record/replay these actions with pin-point accuracy.

This could one day be transformed into a Online Cricket-playing website where bowler holding this "hyper-ball" in his hand and standing in Australia could bowl to a batsman holding this "hyper-bat" in England. Viewers could join an international match sitting right in front of their PCs/TVs. Run-outs, caught-behinds and LBWs will never again be controversial, and what not.

But that's all a far-fetched dream. Coming back to square 1, the basic step right-now is a chip of a small size that could accurately transmit its position to a PC.

Comment: I don't know whether the specific capabilities you want are available commercially, but the name for the kind of thing you're looking for is “wireless sensor networks”. I hope that helps your research.

Comment: Sounds like you are describing [NTP](http://ntp.org/) for calculating distances (delay). It requires timers clocked well above 1GHz for this application. Similar questions have been asked before, as far as I am aware none of them had an answer.

Comment: 1 mm accuracy at 100 m means 0.001% accuracy. That sounds difficult. It may be difficult for a PC running a normal operating system such as Windows to do much of the timing-critical work itself.

Comment: What is the application? Do you really need such accuracy?

Comment: ~1mm means resolution of a few picoseconds at \$c\$. It's pretty much in the realm of science fiction.

Comment: hmm... so I've hit a wall here; or maybe I'm doing it the wrong way. So let me share and maybe I could get a better advice. Please Read my edit above.

Comment: Differential GPS can probably give you accuracies of a few _cm_. Why do you need 1mm accuracy? It _might_ be achievable with inferometry, but not with obstacles in the field with different propagation speeds. And will probably result in larger units.

Comment: So you need 1mm resolution for objects moving at fairly high speeds. I suppose you will want it to operate from a tiny battery for a few hours, be very small and light, and resistant to very high G forces. This is just not practical, and you need to develop a different approach altogether.

Comment: I think a Wii or a Microsoft Connect could/can already do this with acceptable accuracy and precision. For a _game_ that's all you need. Your specs sound like you're trying to create a wireless surgical operating room.

Answer (score 1):

It is a Real Time Location System (RTLS) application. A god reference book is "
RTLS For Dummies" by Ajay Malik, but technology is at a very early stage.

Atmel developes souch an IC, at the size of 5x5x0.9 mm. but the complete system is much larger. The chip is the AT86RF233 [1](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8351-MCU_Wireless-AT86RF233_Datasheet.pdf)
and the eveluation system is the AVR2152 [2](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8443-RTB-Evaluation-Application-Software-Users-Guide_Application-Note_AVR2152.pdf). The Aapplication is based on ZigBee protocol. Expected accuracy is at the range of plus/minus 30cm (reported at open field).

A pair of evaluation kit costs around 380$, but chip itself costs around 5$.

Comment: Thanks a ton. That's really close to what I'm looking for, except for the size thing. BTW, I just scrolled through the specs and nowhere it talks about the capabilities of the system, i.e. max measurement range, accuracy etc.

Comment: mmm... 30cm is the showstopper here. As I said, I need a device with no more than +/- 1mm error.

Comment: 100 meters and not line of sight suggest that Zigbee is very much unsuitable.

Comment: @ Lundin but ZigBee RF4CE specification for remote control applications allow no line-of-sight. In any case the design is targeting for low cost devices

Comment: @dotNET in this case you need circuitry to detect 3.33psec phase differences, that is not available now in electronics. Maybe in interferometers area only. However, since the popularity on this application it is increasing considerably, you have to wait a bit and track companies and organizations announcements on this subject.

Comment: Somebody downvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want to measure travel times without line of sight. That eliminates sound waves. Have to use electromagnetics. Light travels one millimeter in 3.33 picoseconds. To detect that difference you'll need sampling rates of at least three hundred gigahertz, bare minimum. That's faster than the clock rate of any off the shelf chips of which I am aware. That doesn't even account for any necessary high frequency PCB layout or the actual interface between the chip and the transceiver. What you ask may be impracticable.

Comment: What if we compute the average time of say 1000 round trips? Since processing time will be constant, we can easily subtract that from the total time and get avg. time of 1 trip. That will reduce the requirement to 300MHz or something.

Comment: Hm. You'd have to have one system bouncing a thousand messages back and forth, and another timing how long the total set of the thousand messages took. You might get data that way. But then your battery life will go to zero pretty rapidly because of the continuous communication.

Comment: You're also assuming processing time is constant, which it may not be. I mean, we're not just throwing a photon back and forth, the transmission has to have some sort of data content. The arrival of that data takes additional time, and guaranteeing constant processing time with dozens of nodes all broadcasting at once seems like it might be problematic.